# Своя сортировка в JSON

Tags: c++, json, qt

Пытаюсь записать в `JSON` файл данные вот таким кодом

```
{
    QJsonObject dataIndex;

    QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
                                                    tr("Flugweg spreichern"), "",
                                                    tr("Wegpunkt Datei (*.wpf)"));
    QFile file(filename);
    for(int i = 0; i < MapView->waypointData.size(); i++){
        dataIndex.insert(QString("waypoint00%1").arg(MapView->waypointData[i].iD), QString("%1, %2, %3").arg(MapView->waypointData[i].lng, 0, 'f', 5).arg(MapView->waypointData[i].lat, 0, 'f', 5).arg(MapView->waypointData[i].alt, 0, 'f', 5));
    }
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QJsonDocument json_doc(dataIndex);
    QString json_string = json_doc.toJson();
    QFile save_file(filename);
    if(!save_file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
        qDebug() << "failed to open save file";
    }
    save_file.write(json_string.toLocal8Bit());
    save_file.close();
}
```

Получаю такой вывод:

```
{
    "waypoint000": "10.14200, 52.99339, 0.00000",
    "waypoint001": "10.15273, 52.99664, 0.00000",
    "waypoint0010": "10.17547, 52.98598, 0.00000",
    "waypoint0011": "10.17605, 52.98421, 0.00000",
    "waypoint0012": "10.17597, 52.98104, 0.00000",
    "waypoint0013": "10.17561, 52.97992, 0.00000",
    "waypoint0014": "10.17389, 52.97810, 0.00000",
    "waypoint0015": "10.17194, 52.97723, 0.00000",
    "waypoint0016": "10.16719, 52.97632, 0.00000",
    "waypoint0017": "10.15920, 52.97585, 0.00000",
    "waypoint0018": "10.15561, 52.97572, 0.00000",
    "waypoint002": "10.15971, 52.99664, 0.00000",
    "waypoint003": "10.16554, 52.99577, 0.00000",
    "waypoint004": "10.16928, 52.99421, 0.00000",
    "waypoint005": "10.17058, 52.99326, 0.00000",
    "waypoint006": "10.17130, 52.99235, 0.00000",
    "waypoint007": "10.17288, 52.99053, 0.00000",
    "waypoint008": "10.17389, 52.98949, 0.00000",
    "waypoint009": "10.17453, 52.98819, 0.00000",
    "waypoint0099": "10.14107, 52.97970, 0.00000"
}
```

Как заставить `JSON` сохронять 0010, после 009? Читал, что сортировки так таковой нету в JSON.

Comment: Порядок объектов, действительно, не гарантирован. Он и не нужен, ведь к ним обращаются по ключам. Для упорядочения существуют массивы.

Comment: @КириллМалышев даже если обращение по ключам, все равно исход у меня получается не правильный. Дабы не исправлять множество функций. Хочу сделать порядок объектов

Comment: Если работать с JSON как с JSON, а не как со строкой, проблем возникнуть не может. Может, вам удобнее будет такая структура https://pastebin.com/WGJWNKkW ? Только как делать это в C++ я не знаю.

Comment: Открываем википедию: *Объект — это неупорядоченное множество пар ключ:значение*. Все, ответ на ваш вопрос - никак. Если хотите сохранять порядок, используйте массив. Или генерируйте json вручную.

Comment: @КириллМалышев на python делал тоже подобное.. а вот на C++ что-то не хочет

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb как сгенирировать вручную?

Comment: @Insider, ручками, в цикле, конкатенацией, повторяя всю структуру. Но, если вы составляете JSON вручную, парсите его вручную, зачем вообще вам JSON? Используйте CSV какой-нибудь

Comment: @КириллМалышев чтобы потом его прочитать https://pastebin.com/6NgPMnrs

Comment: Так он у вас и считаться таким образом должен не в том порядке, как в файле, а по возрастанию ключей

Comment: @КириллМалышев Вообще, с 00 перед цифрой работало, не знаю что сделал, что перестало, хотя этот код вообще не трогал

Comment: @BeardedBeaver если вы про код что в pastebin то считывает почему-то в том порядке, как в файле

Comment: Специально проверил, нет. Поменял в файле порядок строк и вывел порядок ключей в вашем цикле. Ключит отсортированы в алфавитном порядке. Согласен с Кириллом, JSON вам не подходит, используйте CSV если важна возможность чтения/редакции в текстовом редакторе ручками, или вообще бинарный формат, он быстрее для чтения и записи и до кучи компактнее.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver прошу прощение за наглость, не могли бы вы тогда на основе моих действий в коде написать пример сохранение и чтения? С CSV я никогда пока что не работал. Осваивать его сейчас в конце проекта (за 3 дня), времени не особо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запись CSV:

```
QFile file(fileName);
QTextStream stream(&file);
if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    //TODO кинуть исключение, или выдать окно ошибки или ругнуться в лог
    return;
}
for(int i = 0; i < MapView->waypointData.size(); i++)
{
    stream << QString("waypoint00%1, %2, %3, %4\n").arg(MapView->waypointData[i].iD).arg(MapView->waypointData[i].lng, 0, 'f', 5).arg(MapView->waypointData[i].lat, 0, 'f', 5).arg(MapView->waypointData[i].alt, 0, 'f', 5);
}
```

Чтение CSV:

```
QFile file(fileName);
QTextStream stream(&file);
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    //TODO кинуть исключение, или выдать окно ошибки или ругнуться в лог
    return;
}
QString buf;
QStringList list;
while (!stream.atEnd())
{
    buf = stream.readLine();
    list = buf.split(",");   //разделение делается по запятым, убедитесь, что разделитель целой и дробной части в координатах точка, не запятая
    if (list.size() < 4)    //если вдруг попалась пустая или битая строка
        continue;

    WaypointData* w = new WaypointData();
    //TODO проверить корректность конвертации с помощью bool параметра, передаваемого в 
    w->alt = list[1].trimmed().toDouble();    //возможно, trimmed можно убрать, эта функция убирает пробелы по краям строки
    w->lng = list[2].trimmed().toDouble();
    w->lat = list[3].trimmed().toDouble();
    w->state = 0;
    QString id = list[0];
    w->iD = id.remove(0,8).toInt();
    MapView->AddWaypoint(*w);
}
```

Код записи вейпоинта скопирован из вашего кода, проверьте, что все правильно делается.

Comment: Спасибо большое, один вопрос key у меня  `QString line = obj[key].toString();` т.е цифра (0-99) тут получается это `list[0].toDouble();` ?

Comment: Да, все верно, недоисправил код. Только не `toDouble()` а просто `list[0]`, имя вейпоинта это строка.